# What is the rigorous way for a Lie group (SU(n)) element to be "near" another element?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

**Statement of the problem**

I'm working with a function $\lambda : SU(n)\times SU(n)\times SU(n) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Given $U_1, U_2, U_3 \in SU(n)$, I'd like to know how to calculate $\lambda (\tilde{U}_1, \tilde{U}_2, \tilde{U}_3)$, where $\tilde{U}_i$ is some $SU(n)$ element in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $U_i$.

---

**The attempt at a solution**

Two ideas:

1. I know that any $U\in SU(n)$ that is in a small neighborhood of the identity can be written as

\begin{align}
U = I + i \epsilon X + O(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}

where $X \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, the algebra of traceless hermitian matrices. So then is it correct to say that **any** element in a neighborhood of $U_1$ can be written as

\begin{align}
U_1(I + i \epsilon X + O(\epsilon^2))
\end{align}

for some $X \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$?

---

2. Define a 1-parameter family $U_1(t)= e^{i X_1 t}$ such that

\begin{align}
U_1(0) = I, \hspace{5mm}U_1(1) = U_1
\end{align}

Claim: then any element in a neighborhood of $U_1$ is given by

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} U(t)\bigg|_{t=1} = e^{i X_1} ( i X_1) = i U_1 X_1
\end{align}

But $i U_1 X_1$ isn't unitary, so this must be wrong. Aside: why was this the wrong approach?

Comment: Asking how to "treat" a function is rather vague and wishy-washy. What kind of explicit, clear, objective mathematical aims do you have in mind? Anyway, your (1) is true. For (2), the better question is why it would even be right in the first place. If we consider differentiable functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, there's no reason to think of $f'(x+1)$ as an approximation to $f(x)$! Rather, Taylor's approximation is $f(x+1)\approx f(x)+f'(x)$. Indeed, your approach in (1) is the correct way of generalizing Taylor's approximation.

Comment: You're right, the question was too vague, please see my edit above. Thanks for clearing up (2), I realize that all I did was find an element of the tangent space at $U_1$ instead of an element of the group in a neighborhood of $U_1$, similar to your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of marking this question answered: as per anon's comment, approach 1. that I outlined in the question is of course the correct way to proceed.